# How to cancel UIBarbuttonItem setTitle shining effect

Tags: ios, title, uibarbuttonitem, effect

[image: the screen shot of my project]

Like image shows, I used UIBarbuttonItem as rightBarButtonItem, what I want to do is just change rightBarButton's title when I select a picture or deselect a picture, so I used code like this:

```
[self.rightBarButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"完成（%@/%@）",@(_selectedAssets.count),@(self.maxPicturesNum)]];
```

but the barbutton will show shin when its text changed, I try to use UIButton instead of UIBarButtonItem, and shin effect disappear indeed, but UIButton will be close to right bounds far, can you help me?

[image: thr screen shot of my project with UIButton]

Comment: Try setting the button title by simply accessing its title property:

Comment: but I change barbuttonitem's title,there will be shining animation,and I need't the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `UIButton` and assign it to your `rightBarButton`

```
UIButton *rightButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
[rightButton setBackgroundImage:someImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
rightButton.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"完成（%@/%@）",@(_selectedAssets.count),@(self.maxPicturesNum)];
rightButton.titleLabel.font = someFont;
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
self.rightBarButton = rightBarButtonItem;
```

And while updating label use `rightButton.titleLabel.text`

For Adjusting label use this:

```
- (void)setTitlePositionAdjustment:(UIOffset)adjustment
                 forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Comment: shouldn't you use                                                                                     UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]?

Comment: and I used  setTitlePositionAdjustment method but I can't see any effect,is there anything I  make wrong?

Comment: @gavinHe Yes you can use buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom too. Can you show me how you have used "setTitlePositionAdjustment'?

Comment: UIOffset offset = {-50,0};      [rightButton setTitlePositionAdjustment:offset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: How about setting the UIButton's text alignment rightButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; or use [rightButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I do like this:

```
- (void)loadRightButtonItem{
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 120, 40);
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
[button setTitle:@"完成（0/9）" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
//    [button setTitleColor:[self.buttonFolder titleColorForState:UIControlStateHighlighted] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onFinishClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 135, 40)];
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];

[view addSubview:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
_rightBarButton = button;
}
```

It cancel the shin effect.

thanks to @RoHaN,your idea did great inspired me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks.